# What is the best way to charge phone's lithium-polymer batteries to optimize battery life?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-polymer

I was looking for tips on how to best charge a phone which comes with a lithium-polymer battery, but most articles online talk about lithium-ion batteries.

Can the same tips, for example those [in this article](https://www.androidauthority.com/maximize-battery-life-882395/), be applied to lithium-polymer batteries?

Comment: Put the essential details of the tips into your question so that (1) we don't have to follow a link to understand the question, (2) so that we know exactly which tip(s) you are asking about and (3) so your question still makes sense when the link dies.

Comment: *lithium-polymer battery, but most articles online talk about lithium-ion batteries.* Li-Ion and Li-Po batteries are similar enough that the "lifetime tips" will apply equally to **both**.

Comment: Realize that the way to get the maximum lifetime out of your phone might **conflict with normal usage**. For example, keeping the battery between 40% and 60 % charged increases battery lifetime but means you have to start and stop charging many times a day and/or stop using your phone when the battery gets below 40%. Are you willing to do that? I'd rather get a phone that allows me to change the battery easily / cheaply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laptop batteries charging myths - Long life OR short life](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475787/laptop-batteries-charging-myths-long-life-or-short-life)

Comment: or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294842/is-it-better-to-keep-lion-battery-charge-on-the-lows-or-the-highs-for-battery-li/294845#294845

Comment: @MarcusMüller no, because these articles don't make the difference between the two types of batteries.

Comment: @Thomas there's no difference. Same technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the same rules to both Li-ion and LiPo batteries. Regarding your question, the parameters under your control when charging a cellphone are the state of charge (%) and the temperature. Lithium technology lifetime suffers in "high energy" conditions, i.e. high temperature and high state of charge. So I can give you two "ideal" advices:

- try to keep your phone's temperature as close as possible to 25°C (especially when charging);
- keep the state of charge inside the 20-80% range, whenever you can afford it.

Bonus tip: prefer charging at low current rate, whenever the charging time is not of the essence, for example using a 1A adaptor instead of an high current adaptor. Low current means less heating of the battery.

Other considerations:

- be careful when charging by means of wireless charging (e.g. Qi): a low quality charger may produce a lot of heat, and this would be a problem since the battery is in direct contact with the charger;
- be careful when charging inside your car; a typical scenario is hanging the phone to use google maps for navigation, while charging: this is quite bad because you are charging while using lot of processing power (which means heat) and the phone is exposed to sunlight (which means more heat).

Comment: Why is it important to keep the state of charge between 20-80%?

Comment: Does it matter to always charge a phone from 20 to 80% or is it better to charge more frequently?

Comment: 20-80% is not an exact figure. The point is to never keep the battery in almost fully charged state, where a lot of energy is stored in the cell, nor in fully discharged state, where low battery voltage means more discharging current. Using the battery in the range 0-100% will not destroy your battery: it was designed to work in this range. But here we are talking about maximizing the cicle life.
In my opinion, don't bother frequent partial charging, since it won't be a problem for battery life.

Comment: So, a lot of energy in a fully charged state produces more heat, right? But why does low battery voltage produces more current and thus more heat?

Comment: Not exactly. You can think about it like this: the higher the state of charge, the more chemically reactive the cell is. Similarly, less energy stored means that the battery is more chemically inert.
A low voltage means higher current because usually the load (cellphone) uses a dc-dc converter to stabilize the voltage supply for the electronics, which uses the same power, regardless of the battery voltage.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean with low voltage. If I understand correctly, because phones try to stabilize the voltage, a low voltage means that the phone will have to do more work to level the voltage than what it would have to do if the phone was already at a level voltage. I still don't understand why having a higher state of charges decreases the battery life. What does it mean concretely for the battery to be more reactive? Why does would it decrease its lifetime?

Comment: I'm no chemistry expert, so I'm not able to explain it to you in simple terms. But, have a look at this very interesting document, paragraph 2.2.1. Btw, this document seems to answer all our questions about Li-ion battery life. http://css.umich.edu/sites/default/files/publication/CSS20-08.pdf